# multiple prefixes for @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have an **application.properties** file with the following content.

```
server.name
server.id
server.ipadd
```

and I am using the following annotation to read  in **configProperties.java**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server")
private String name;
private String ipadd;
```

Now I have included extra properties.

```
server.client.type
server.client.location
```

and want to read these new properties. How can I read these in the same **configProperties.java** file?
Looking for something like the following formats which includes multiple prefixes, I know these are invalid.

```
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server", prefix = "server.client")
or
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server.client")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new class like

```
public class ClientProperties {
   private String type;
   private String location;
}
```

and in your configuration prefixed with server you add it

```
private String name;
private String ipadd;
private ClientProperties client;
```

Comment: in that case, I have to use these new properties as configProperties.getClientProperties().getLocation(); which will be cumbersome. Any other suggestions? @ole-bille

Comment: I have tried the above approach and it's not working as expected.

Comment: can you show me the configuration classes you have created and the property file?

Comment: it worked after renaming class name clientproperties to client same as the child key name.

Comment: Its not using the class name when it sets the properties so that doesnt make sence. Its using the variable name. Ive just tested it and it works fine.

Comment: I will recheck it once tomorrow.

Comment: I have re-tested it, its not working once I changed the class name

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what you are trying to do.

```
@Configuration
public class MultipleConfigPrefixExample {
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config.first.part")
  public FirstPart getFirstPart(){
    return new FirstPart();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "info.another.part")
  public AnotherPart getAnotherPart(){
    return new AnotherPart();
  }

  @Getter
  @Setter
  public static class FirstPart {
    private String element1;
    private String element2;
  }


  @Getter
  @Setter
  public static class AnotherPart {
    private String element1;
    private String element2;
  }
}
```

Annotations `@Getter @Setter` are from lombok.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question about

> configProperties.getClientProperties().getLocation()

I had to deal with a similar thing, and you can just wrap that call in your ConfigProperties class that looks like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public ConfigProperties{
    private String name;
    private String ipadd;
    private ClientProperties client;
    public static class ClientProperties {
       private String type;
       private String location;
    }
    public String getType(){return client.getType();}
}
```

So your internal structure is correct, but you can access the properties from the top-level class. In my case I was using generated git properties that I couldn't reformat and this was easier than re-generating the files.